# Searching specific text then validate in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out if this is possible.
I have an excel spreadsheet with the following column

[image: Column N]

I want to validate/Compare the highlighted portion to an Xlookup column I have
[image: xlookup column]

I'm trying to validate line by line that what I see in column N highlighted matches column BD highlighted. It only needs to match one of the highlighted items. I am attempting to filter this down by using =IsNumber(Search but that only goes so far.

Is there any formula, or even VBA code that could compare and validate to se if what's in Column N is also in Column BD?
Any help on this would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic used to get the text you highlighted? It would also be helpful to explain what the test used for validation is.

Comment: The Highlighted text is just text. The text is a unique identifier. I'm trying to validate that the character string I see in column N has the same string somewhere in column BD. If they match "True" if they don't "False". Hopefully that helps, but let me know if you need more info. Example In Column N(2) JTA-475MC appears in Column BD so I want this to return "True"

Comment: It's possible yes, through formulae in ms365. Do you have markdown sample data? With expected results and your own attempt would be appreciated.

Comment: An example of the logic of text would be "The text is a unique identifier **that is always before the first space in the string**" or something like that. We don't know how your data is setup, you should explain that to us

Comment: I guess I don't understand what your asking me for, The data is as I show it above. Column N is just text, Column BD is also text, Column BE uses the following formula `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(N2,BD2,2))` and I've been playing with xlookup as an attempt to do what I want it to do `=ISTEXT(SEARCH(LEFT(N2,5),XLOOKUP(N2,BD2,"True","False",2)))` but obviously this isn't working either. If there was a way to get a formula to look at the string in N before the First space and then look in BD for that string sequence anywhere in the cell that would be perfect. (Minus the # in column N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to get the text up to, but not including, the first space, I would do:

```
=left(A1,find(" ",A1,1)-1)
```

Then you could use that to do a vlookup:

```
=vlookup(left(A1,find(" ",A1,1)-1),range-to-look-in,2,0)
```

But you could look in column 1 as well.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going through and so far so good! This spreadsheet has been a nightmare and they wouldn't let me set something up in an Access database to make things easier. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Deke index() with match() can be more flexible than vlookup if the data is not in a convenient order…